# Undefined reference in main Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I did a sample project in linux but i am getting error while running main Makefile

**Project Info:**

**project/database folder** having files database.h , database.cpp , bulid-database ,Makefile

**database.h**

```
/*data base file*/
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class mydatabase
{
public:
    mydatabase(int a , int b);
    int sum(){return m_a +m_b;}
    int diff(){return m_a -m_b;}
    int mul(){return m_a *m_b;}
    float div(){return m_a /m_b;}
    int reminder(){return m_a %m_b;}

private:
    int m_a , m_b;
};
```

**database.cpp**

```
#include "database.h"
mydatabase::mydatabase(int a ,int b):m_a(a) , m_b(b)
{
}
```

**bulid-database**

```
make
if [ -f libdatabase.a ];
then
   echo "Database-Library Build Success"
   cp libdatabase.a ../LIBs/
else
    echo "databse-Library Build Failure"
fi
```

**Makefile**

```
HEADERFILES = $(wildcard *.h)
CPPFILES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJFILES = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o ,$(wildcard *.cpp))
$(OBJFILES): %.o : %.cpp $(HEADERFILES)
    g++ -c -o $@ $<
    ar ruv libdatabase.a $@
    ranlib libdatabase.a
```

**project/Main folder** having files  main.cpp , Makefile

**main.cpp**

```
#include "database.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    mydatabase *obj = new mydatabase(10 ,5);
    std::cout<<"sum is"<<obj->sum()<<endl;
    std::cout<<"diff is"<<obj->diff()<<endl;
    std::cout<<"mul is"<<obj->mul()<<endl;
    std::cout<<"div is"<<obj->div()<<endl;
    std::cout<<"reminder is"<<obj->reminder()<<endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC        = g++
INCPATH  = -I. \
       -I.. \
       -I../database
LIBPATH  = -L../LIBs
LDFLAGS   = ${LIBPATH}/libdatabase.a
CFLAGS    = ${INCPATH} 
testdate:main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o testdate main.o $(LDFLAGS)
main.o:main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

**ISSUE:** database make file is working fine but main Makefile i am having some issue like

**Error:** main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to`mydatabase::mydatabase(int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If you're going to use `new`, you must `delete` that object when you're done with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o testdate $(LDFLAGS) main.o
```

because the library should be specificed AFTER the object `main.o` on the line. This is due to the way the linker handles the objects. Look at this example:

```
gcc -o test someobject.o library.a
```

The linker will:

1. look up all undefined references of `someobject.o` and store them
2. then it opens `library.a` and resolves the undefined references via `library.a`
3. then it closes `library.a`

If the object and the library are in the other way around, then the linker opens `library.a`, sees no undefined references in its table and closes it. Then it tries and compiles `someobject.o` and the undefined references are never satisfied

**EDIT**:
This is a well-known caveat of GCC, a more detailed stack-overflow explanation can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc/409470#409470), and options `--start-group` and `--end-group` can help resolve cases where A depends on B, and B depends on A.

Answer (score 1):

It's your `Makefile`.  You want:

```
libdatabase.a
```

or

```
-ldatabase
```

at the end of your `main` compile line